# Similar path in different routes are getting mismatched

Tags: kong

I have two services setup in Kong, with routes defined in this like this

- Service 1 -> route_service1 -> `(paths)/services/getAccountTypeNew`
- Service 2 -> route_service2 -> `(paths)/services/getAccountType`

When a call comes in for `/services/getAccountTypeNew`, the service and route it is matching is Service 2 and routing the request to Service2 and getting a 404.

How can I fix this?

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Which version of Kong do you use?

Comment: Can you share your configuration ?
Have you tried with `X-Kong-Debug: 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a classic one, in the Route configuration path parameter is a regex.

`/services/getAccountType` is matching `/services/getAccountTypeNew`

You need to add `$` to avoid this

```
    methods:
    - GET
    paths:    
    - /services/getAccountType$
```